# Replace all "+" with "%20" using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In the following text:

"123+456+789"

How can I replace all the "+" characters with %20?
The examples I have seen that use regular expressions end up treating the + as part of the rules used by the expression, so it seems regular expressions cannot be used.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @TryingToImprove — That would give `%2B` not `%20`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to escape the `+` first, which is done with a backslash:

```js
const str = "123+456+789";
console.log(
  str.replace(/\+/g, '%20')
);
```

The same thing is true for any character with a special meaning in a regular expression, like parentheses, `*`, `^`, and so on - to match a *literal* character, put a backslash in front of it. (Same for the backslash itself - `\\` matches a literal backslash)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to remove all plusses and replace them with `%20`:

```js
let plus = "123+456+789";

let percent = plus.split("+").join("%20");

console.log(percent)
```

Comment: Likely because it's very inefficient

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by using str replace

```
str = document.getElementById("mystring").innerHTML;
res = str.replace("+", "%20");
```

Comment: That replaces only the first instance. The example data in the question has 2 `+`s in the string.